# How to remove part of filename and add extension programmatically?

Tags: bash, unix, command-line

I have hundreds of files in one folder named like this:

```
index.html?tab=This is - the file name
```

I would like to remove "index.html?tab=" part and add extension ".txt" to all files. How can I do this using Unix command line tools (I'm using MacOSX 10.6.2)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In bash,

```
for i in index.html\?tab\=*; do mv "$i" "${i:15}.txt"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for file in index.html\?*
do
   mv "$file" "${file#*=}".txt
done
```